# How to prevent a dropdownlist from postback or updating inside an updatepanel when button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

How to prevent a dropdownlist from postback or updating inside an updatepanel when button is clicked.
I am doing this because i have java script to make ddl a searchable dropdownlist. i have a few labels, textboxes, gridviews and dropdownlist inside an update panel. when i click view button dropdownlist turns back into normal dropdown insteads of searchable dropdown.

[image: Simple DDL]
[image: Searchable DDL]

```
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSector" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStdID" runat="server" Width="92px" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnView" runat="server" Text="View" onclick="btnView_Click" AccessKey="V"/>
<table>
    <tr><td><b>Qualification</b></td><td><b>Exemption Type</b></td></tr>
    <tr>              
    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQualification" class="chzn-select" runat="server" Width="225px" onselectedindexchanged="ddlQualification_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AutoPostBack="false"></asp:DropDownList></td>
    <td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExemType" runat="server" Width="225px">
    </asp:DropDownList></td>        
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<script src="../Searchable DDL/jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="../Searchable DDL/chosen.jquery.js"type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(".chzn-select").chosen(); 
 $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though there is no full PostBack, everything inside the UpdatePanel still gets refreshed and so the DOM loses the elements that were modified with jquery.

You need to call the function that created the searchable dropdownlists after a async PostBack also.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        createSearchDropDown();
    });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        createSearchDropDown();
    });

    function createSearchDropDown() {
        $(".chzn-select").chosen(); 
        $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have uploaded my java script code kindly check it. i am still unable to solve the issue.\

Answer (score 0):

Write your javascript function in pageLoad event of javascript.

It will always be executed in postback as well as partial postbacks also.

Find below code for your functions

```
 function pageLoad() {
             //This will ensure your code will run all the time
             CreateDropdown();
             InitializeDatePickers();
             AssignPlugins();

        }
```

Comment: This is my javasrcript code. how can i call it on inside page load event?

`<script src="../Searchable DDL/jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>  
 <script src="../Searchable DDL/chosen.jquery.js"type="text/javascript"></script>  
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(".chzn-select").chosen(); 
 $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });</script>`

Comment: could you try below code   <script src="../Searchable DDL/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Searchable DDL/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad() {
            $(".chzn-select").chosen();
            $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
        }

    </script>