# Implement JQuery Datatable in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatables

I want to use "JQuery Datatable" with ASP.NET GridView.

I tried something i found, but it didn't work.

**GridView -**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewTasks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="task_id" HeaderText="TaskID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="task_description" HeaderText="Task Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="task_detail" HeaderText="Task Detail" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="task_createdate" HeaderText="Create Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="task_targetdate" HeaderText="Target Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="task_isReaded" HeaderText="Task Read" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="product_id" HeaderText="ProductID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="product_name" HeaderText="Product" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="status_id" HeaderText="StatusID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="status_name" HeaderText="Status" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="severity_id" HeaderText="SeverityID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="severity_name" HeaderText="Severity" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_masterID" HeaderText="MasterID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="gorevi_veren" HeaderText="Master" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_slaveID" HeaderText="SlaveID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="görevi_alan" HeaderText="Slave" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="task_score" HeaderText="Score" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**JavaScript -**

**1**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#gridViewTasks').DataTable();} );
```

**2**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$("#gridViewTasks").prepend( $("<thead></thead>").append( $(this).find("tr:first") ) ).DataTable() ;} );
```

**Script And CSS i used -**

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

**And also i tried girdView_PreRender Function**

i am adding references in GridView when i use.

```
protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // You only need the following 2 lines of code if you are not 
    // using an ObjectDataSource of SqlDataSource
    gridViewTasks.DataSource = Sample.GetData();
    gridViewTasks.DataBind();

    if (gridViewTasks.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        //This replaces <td> with <th> and adds the scope attribute
        gridViewTasks.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
        //This will add the <thead> and <tbody> elements
        gridViewTasks.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

        //This adds the <tfoot> element. 
        //Remove if you don't have a footer row
        gridViewTasks.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;

    }
}
```

**Code Behind - i am using Linq to SQL**

```
var sorgu = from gorev in db.Tasks
join ga in db.Users on gorev.user_slaveID equals ga.user_id
join gv in db.Users on gorev.user_masterID equals gv.user_id
join product in db.Products on gorev.product_id equals product.product_id
join severity in db.Severities on gorev.severity_id equals severity.severity_id
join status in db.Status on gorev.status_id equals status.status_id
select new
{
    gorev.task_id,
    gorev.task_description,
    gorev.task_detail,
    gorev.task_createdate,
    gorev.task_targetdate,
    gorev.task_isReaded,
    product.product_id,
    product.product_name,
    status.status_id,
    status.status_name,
    severity.severity_id,
    severity.severity_name,
    gorev.user_masterID,
    gorevi_veren = gv.user_username,
    gorev.user_slaveID,
    görevi_alan = ga.user_username,
    gorev.task_score                       
};

gridViewTasks.DataSource = sorgu;
gridViewTasks.DataBind();
```

So, How can i implement Jquery DataTable in ASP.NET GridView.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These few lines are all you need to get it working. You don't need the prerender event. Just bind in `Page_Load` in the `IsPostBack` check. I did add a `RowDataBound` event to the `GridView` to add the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` sections programatically rather than with jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check for a postback
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //bind the gridview data
        GridView1.DataSource = source;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is the header row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        //add the thead and tbody section programatically
        e.Row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
}
```

UPDATE

If you are using a DataTable inside an UpdatePanel, use the following javascript to ensure proper binding after an Async PostBack.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        createDataTable();
    });

    createDataTable();

    function createDataTable() {
        $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').DataTable();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it worked.Thanks for your help. But , there are things i didn't understand exactly. Can you explain briefly ? 

1-) What is the .ClientID ? Why we use it ?
2-) And why we use RowDataBound event ?

Comment: 1) aspnet can rename the ID of a control on the clientside, so `gridViewTasks` could become `PlaceHolder`_GridView1`. If that happens then `$("#gridViewTasks")` will not work because that ID does not exist. Using `ClientID` will make sure you use the correct ID in the client side.

Comment: 2) In this case the RowDataBound event is meant to add `<thead>` and `<tbody>` to the gridview, which is not present by default. It replaces your `$("#gridViewTasks").prepend( $("<thead></thead>").append( $(this).find("tr:first")`. But you could remove it if you wish to use the jQuery method to add them.

Comment: OK. Thank you so much. Finally, Do you know how i added Excell,Print etc. buttons in Jquery DataTable ? İf you know, can you share with me ?

Comment: Sorry, that I don't know.

Comment: May i ask one more thing ?

i add the edit button that is opened as modal popup in GridView.

When i click the edit button then modal popup is opened and jquery Table modules disappears. After page refreshing modules come back.

How can i fix the problem ? So, when i click the edit button, Jquery Table modules doesn't disappear.

Comment: If the datatable is gone, you have to call `$('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').DataTable();` again. If you use an UpdatePanel use the PageRequestManager https://stackoverflow.com/a/45442175/5836671

Answer (score 2):

Try this, It will work as per your need.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvExample" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <%-- Binding Expression--%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Call necessary CSS(bootstrap.css, font-awesome.css..etc)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />
```

Call necessary scripts(bootstrap.js, jquery.js ..etc)

```
<!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<!-- Popper.JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- jQuery Data Tables CDN -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Data Tables JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"></script>
```

then add this below script

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= gvExample.ClientID%>').prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($("#<%= gvExample.ClientID%>").find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
            stateSave: true,
        });
    });
</script>
```