# Grid search option disappears

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, grid-search, aspxgridview

In my ASP.NET form using VB.Net, i have two grids that display information based on selections made in dropdownlists associated with each grid. After making the first selection of values for the first grid, its data is loaded. Then i select the values for the second grid.

Each grid has a search option, which after appearing when the respective grid is loaded, ends up disappearing when i make a new selection in the dropdownlist, and i am unable to make it reappear.

[image]

How can i make the search option not disappear after reselecting from the dropdown?

Comment: This is probably the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49443894/implement-jquery-datatable-in-asp-net-gridview