# Why does JQuery function returns undefined in update panel

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, reporting-services

I have this jquery code that disables an export option in srss.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    hideOptions();
  });

  function hideOptions() {
    var MHTMLid = $("a[onclick=\"$find('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewerControl1_ReportViewer1').exportReport('PDF');\"]").parent().parent().attr("id");
    $("#" + MHTMLid + " div:nth-child(4)").css('display', 'none');
    console.log(MHTMLid);
  }
</script>
```

It should search and hide the PDF option. The issue is it works on most pages however it fails to alter the display options of reports that are within update panels. My guess is that the update panel is messing with the Jquery operations.

What are your recommendations. I cannot remove the update panels from the pages.

Comment: You have to execute `hideOptions()` again after Async PostBack. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45442175/5836671

Comment: Where do I put that code? I dont understand the answer you linked @VDWWD

Comment: Please could you put this as an answer so I could mark it correct! Thanks for the help. It worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an UpdatePanel, you need to rebind jQuery to DOM elements within the UpdatePanel because the original ones are lost due to the update.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        hideOptions();
    });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        hideOptions();
    });

    function hideOptions() {
        var MHTMLid = $("a[onclick=\"$find('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewerControl1_ReportViewer1').exportReport('PDF');\"]").parent().parent().attr("id");
        $("#" + MHTMLid + " div:nth-child(4)").css('display', 'none');
        console.log(MHTMLid);
    }
</script>
```